# For a real $n \times n$ matrix $A$ if $x^tA^tx \geq 0 \;\forall \;x,$ then $Au=0 $ iff $A^tu=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix such that $x^tA^tx \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then how can I show that $Au=0 $ if and only if $A^tu=0$ ?

Since $A$ and $A^t$ have  the same rank enough to show that kernel of one of them is contained in the kernel of  another. I need some help.

Comment: Suppose $Au=0$.  Look at what you get for $x=A^tu+\lambda u$ in $x^tA^tx\geq 0$.

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be symmetric?

Comment: A is not symmetric.

Comment: @user10354138's hint works, but I think it is more natural to consider $(tu-v)^TA(tu-v)$ for any scalar $t$ and any vector $v$.